# How to grab variables from a library function that is already returning a template to view in PHP/Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, web-scraping

I have a a library stripping out a web-page of it's data for view, but am having trouble getting the variables back to my model/insert. So far I have in my

model...

```
...
function update_related($related_array)
{
    $this->db->set($related_array);
    $this->db->insert('related_products');
}
```

in my

controller...

```
...
public function index()
{
    $data = array();

    if(isset($_GET['url']))
    {
        $data['url'] = trim($_GET['url']);
        if(!empty( $data['url']))
        {
            $this->load->library('scraping');
            $data['page'] = $this->scraping->curlFunc($data['url']);
        }else{
            $data['notice'] = 'URL is empty!!!';
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('view_x', $data);

    $this->load->model('Model_x','', TRUE); 
    $related_array = array(
        'x_id' => $var0,
        'freq_together' => $var1,
        'also_bought' => $var2,
        'created_at' => $var3
    );
    $this->Model_x->update_related($related_array);

}
```

library (much longer than this but you get the idea)...

```
public function curlFunc($url)
{
...
$shdom = $shdom.'<p>Bought Together: ';
    foreach($shdom2->find('.class td a') as $e) {
        if (preg_match('/F00([^\/]*)/i', $e, $regs))
        {
            $r = $regs[0];
            $shdom = $shdom.$r.',';
            $Var1 = $r; //take note, this is a variable I need for Model insert
...
}
    return $shdom;
}
```

I am trying to return data from here, without re-running this scraping process more than once. More important, I just want a clean,fast way to get my data into the database and keep the view as is. Fairly new to Codeigniter/MVC (actually chose this project to improve MVC knowledge) so any alterations to my process is welcome.

view...

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <span>URL: </span>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="url" id="url"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="GO!">
</form><br />
<?php
if (isset($page)){
    echo'<hr />';
    echo $page;
}
if (isset($notice)){

    echo "<h3>$notice</h3>";
}
?>
```

Comment: what about loading the model inside the library ?

Comment: @AhmedSamy I tried this and was given an error. But that was what made the most sense to me at first and could need to code differently. I simply don't have enough experience with this process though. I get - - - Message: Undefined property: Scraping::$load - - -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i know what are you missing here,
In codeigniter in library level Codeigniter instance is not availble so you need to load it

by adding this in your  library construct or whatever fits your need

`$this->ci =& get_instance();`

so you have access to codeigniter core classes like `load`

you can easily load your model now by
`$this->ci->load->model('model_name');`

ref [Creating Libraries](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Comment: That did the trick, +1 and a check! I will have to read the link as well, thank you.